# AdSense reaches 98% of web browser CPU

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control, adsense

I have a strange problem with AdSense. When I scroll down the web page with auto ads, at the bottom the browser crashed because "the page doesn't respond".

Checking the Dev Tool I discovered that AdSense processes reach 98% of CPU. This only occurs when I reach bottom of the page.

Any idea how can I debug further?

[image]

Comment: Is your page available publicly? I don't think you can debug it yourself, but maybe adsense engineers can take a look.

Comment: You are right. As suggested in AdSense forum, I disabled overlay ads for screen greater than 1000px and problem is solved.

Comment: Could you still share the link to your page? What you are describing shouldn't happen. There is probably a bug in AdSense code and we'd like to understand it better and fix it.

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau I disabled the ads for screen greater than 1000px so now it doesn't occur anymore. Do you need enyway the link to check something?

Comment: Yes, it would be useful. Maybe something on your site (unusual DOM) causes that 98% CPU issue. We can force ads locally so it shouldn't be a problem even if you disabled them.

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau https://www.deskaeronautico.it/